# How can I dynamically invoke the same scala function in cascading manner with output of previous call goes as input to the next call

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

I am new to Spark-Scala and trying following thing but I am stuck up and not getting on how to achieve this requirement. I shall be really thankful if someone can really help in this regards.

1. We have to invoke different rules on different columns of given table. The list of column names and rules is being passed as argument to the program
2. The resultant of first rule should go as input to the next rule input.

question : How can I execute exec() function in cascading manner with dynamically filling the arguments for as many rules as specified in arguments.

I have developed a code as follows.

```
object Rules {

    def main(args: Array[String]) = {

            if (args.length != 3) {
                println("Need exactly 3 arguments in format : <sourceTableName> <destTableName> <[<colName>=<Rule> <colName>=<Rule>,...")
                println("E.g : INPUT_TABLE OUTPUT_TABLE [NAME=RULE1,ID=RULE2,TRAIT=RULE3]");
                System.exit(-1)
            }
            val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("My-Rules").setMaster("local");
            val sc = new SparkContext(conf);
            val srcTableName = args(0).trim();
            val destTableName = args(1).trim();
            val ruleArguments = StringUtils.substringBetween(args(2).trim(), "[", "]");
            val businessRuleMappings = ruleArguments.split(",").map(_.split("=")).map(arr => arr(0) -> arr(1)).toMap;

            val sqlContext : SQLContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc) ;
            val hiveContext : HiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc);          
            val dfSourceTbl = hiveContext.table("TEST.INPUT_TABLE");

            def exec(dfSource: DataFrame,columnName :String ,funName: String): DataFrame = {
                    funName match {
                    case "RULE1" => TransformDF(columnName,dfSource,RULE1);
                    case "RULE2" => TransformDF(columnName,dfSource,RULE2);
                    case "RULE3" => TransformDF(columnName,dfSource,RULE3);
                    case _ =>dfSource;
                    }
            }

            def TransformDF(x:String, df:DataFrame, f:(String,DataFrame)=>DataFrame) : DataFrame = {
                    f(x,df);
            }

            def RULE1(column : String, sourceDF: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
                    //put businees logic
                    return sourceDF;
            }

            def RULE2(column : String, sourceDF: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
                    //put businees logic
                    return sourceDF;
            }

            def RULE3(column : String,sourceDF: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
                    //put businees logic
                    return sourceDF;
            }

            // How can I call this exec() function with output casacing and arguments for variable number of rules. 
            val finalResultDF = exec(exec(exec(dfSourceTbl,"NAME","RULE1"),"ID","RULE2"),"TRAIT","RULE3);

            finalResultDF.write.mode(org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode.Append).insertInto("DB.destTableName")       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write all the rules as functions transforming one dataframe to another:

```
val rules: Seq[(DataFrame) => DataFrame] = Seq(
  RULE1("NAME",_:DataFrame),
  RULE2("ID",_:DataFrame),
  RULE3("TRAIT",_:DataFrame)
)
```

Not you can apply them using folding

```
val finalResultDF = rules.foldLeft(dfSourceTbl)(_ transform _)
```